# How can I cancel a vote down?

Tags: discussion, community

Moments ago I mistakenly voted a question down, I'd like to undo that action but can't find out how. If I press the up vote button the voting count goes up by two units (which makes sense) but what I need is something like cancel vote. Thanks.

Comment: click it again.

Comment: Click the down vote arrow again.

Comment: If I click the down vote again I get the message: "You last voted on this question 1 hour ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited". Radu explains the reasons below. Thanks to whomever moved the question to Meta, I wasn't aware of its existence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can cancel a downvote or upvote only a few seconds after your vote by clicking the downvote or upvote sign again. If more then a few seconds have been past, you can't cancel your vote, only if that question/answer was edited.

So, if you can't cancel your vote anymore, this is the only possibility: find a way to edit somehow that question/answer. If your edit will be accepted, after you can retreat your vote.

Answer (score 0):

Just click the downvote sign again and it should remove the downvote. The same works for upvote button.